# How to share text & image in Google Plus (G+) from Android without using Intent?

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I want to share in `G+.` As I knew there are `G+ API` same as `FaceBook & Twitter`.
I get [this doc](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) and follow the same process.

I have found that we can share via two different like,

- Deep linking
- Interactive posts

And base on that I have to choose `DeepLink` for sharing.

I have reach up to [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share)
but when I try to copy and paste that code in my `new_project` then its not working. says like

`The constructor PlusShare.Builder(Activity) is not visible`.

I found a lot but at the end I get same API link. Don't know how to achieve this task.
I have done sharing in Facebook & Twiiter but not get success in G+.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/#adding_basic_sharing please refer this one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
public void share_image_text_GPLUS() {
    File pictureFile;

    try {
        File rootSdDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        pictureFile = new File(rootSdDirectory, "attachment.jpg");
        if (pictureFile.exists()) {
            pictureFile.delete();
        }
        pictureFile.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

        URL url = new URL("http://img.youtube.com/vi/AxeOPU6n1_M/0.jpg");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int size = 0;
        while ((size = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }
        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.print(e);
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);

    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setText("Hello from Google+!").setType("image/jpeg")
            .setStream(pictureUri).getIntent()
            .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}

    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            share_image_text_GPLUS();

        }
    });
```

Comment: This relies on the user having installed the google + app for android. Otherwise this will crash. Besides, this obviously uses Intents, so this is by no means an answer to this question.

Comment: i do have google+ but still its not working any idea please let me know