# Share a picture on Google+ with Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I can easily share a text in Google+ but when i want to add a picture with the text, i got this message ;

You can only post media items stored in your device.

Here is my code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.smurf.fapiao/" + R.drawable.myimage);


     // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
     Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(getActivity())
        .setType("image/png").setStream(uri)
        .setText(getString(R.string.social_googleplus_text) + " http://www.wangwanglotto.com")
        .getIntent();

    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Do you have any idea ? I tried to put the file in raw or assets folder, but i still get the message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702891/how-to-share-text-image-in-google-plus-g-from-android-without-using-intent

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891382/how-to-share-image-in-google-plus-through-an-android-app