# How to share image+text in google Plus through an android app without using intent?

Tags: android, google-plus

Hello i want to share image with text in google plus but right now i can't find example and source of detail so please help me...thanks

```
File tmpFile = new File("/path/to/image");
final String photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
     getContentResolver(), tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, null);

Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
     .setText("Hello from Google+!")
     .setType("image/jpeg")
     .setStream(Uri.parse(photoUri))
     .getIntent()
     .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

I have this code but i can't use beacuse i want to share image+text using sdk like facebook and twitter etc..

Answer (score 0):

We have libraries in Android for Google+ like facebook & twitter. Details given in link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

Also, you can go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702891/how-to-share-text-image-in-google-plus-g-from-android-without-using-intent) which has same kind of question.

Comment: thanks for your ans but i already do this and completly following but not find good sample..