# how to share image from http url on google plus in android?

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to share an online image to google plus profile. In my app I'm getting the image url now I want to share it on google plus profile.

Comment: I've read to share from device. and this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15757969/1878151 which downloads and then shares. I don't intent to download it

Answer (score 3):

```
   File tmpFile = new File("/path/to/image");
 final String photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
         getContentResolver(), tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, null);

 Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
         .setText("Hello from Google+!")
         .setType("image/jpeg")
         .setStream(Uri.parse(photoUri))
         .getIntent()
         .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

**Below code to download image from url**

```
 try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        return myBitmap;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("getBmpFromUrl error: ", e.getMessage().toString());
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I want to share an image which is on web

Comment: you need to download image and then share.

Comment: can I only download it not saving locally and then share it?

Comment: you can download --> Save --> Share --> Delete Image.